# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_Item(System.String)', store expressions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller

I am developing a realtor's portal for my semester end project and I wanted to generate a list of my listings where the listedByID is equal to a session which is created when the user is logged in.
here is the code

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if ((string)Session["Role"] != "Private Seller")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
            var data = db.tbl_listings.Where(x => x.l_listedByID == (int)Session["uID"]);
            return View(data.ToList());
        }
```

The problem is it is throwing this exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object
>   get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

I have tried this as well:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if ((string)Session["Role"] != "Private Seller")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
            var data = db.tbl_listings.Where(x => x.l_listedByID == (int)Session["uID"]).ToList();
            return View(data);
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am lost and the problem seems to be in the controller only. The problem arises when the code hits the "ToList()" method.

Comment: What is the type of l_listedByID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try store result of `Session["uID"]` outside of linq query.

```
var uID = (int)Session["uID"];
var data = db.tbl_listings.Where(x => x.l_listedByID == uID).ToList();
```

There is a big chance that the problem here is in Session["uID"], since its indexer and its being captured by expression as a method and not by the value it returns.
Then, it cannot be translated to an actual SQL.